# Not able to connect to mongodb running in VM (virtual Machine) from local system

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, mongo-shell

I created an AWS EC2 (ubuntu-20.04) instance and setup a mongo server as per https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

(mongo server is running in default port 27017 and not secured by any username/password)

I am able to connect to it from within the VM (after connecting to VM by SSH), by running the terminal command:

```bash
mongo
```

I have configured EC2 instance's Security Group's inbound rule to access port 27017 from my local system's IP.

however when I try to connect to it from my local system's terminal by command:

```bash
 mongo --host "<public_ip_of_vm>:27017"
```

Its throwing error:

> connecting to:
> mongodb://<public_ip_of_vm>:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
> Error: couldn't connect to server <public_ip_of_vm>:27017, connection attempt
> failed: SocketException: Error connecting to <public_ip_of_vm>:27017 :: caused
> by :: Connection refused : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
> @(connect):2:6 exception: connect failed exiting with code 1

Not sure what's causing this issue, I have checked the ufw rules too.
port 27017 is open.

Comment: "Connection refused" typically indicates, that mongod does not run. Did you set [net.bindIp](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.bindIp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you modify ?

> /etc/mongod.conf

Have a look at this tutorial, especially the step 2. Maybe this helps
https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/

Answer (score 1):

Connection refused means you probably do not have a firewall problem. Connection timeout indicates a firewall issue.

Since you can connect locally via localhost, the error indicates that the mongo process is only listening on localhost.

Edit the file `/etc/mogod.conf`. The interesting line is **bindIp**.

It should look like this for IPv4 only:

```
bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

If you have IPv6 enabled

```
bindIp: ::,0.0.0.0
```

**Warning**: enable authentication first. You might be hacked faster than you might expect.